# Automatically filling in cells in Access

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, database-design

I am starting Access + SQL since I have to transfer some heavy Excel documents into an access database and I am still a newbie in here. I tried something as you can see below but it doesn't work properly, I feel like VBA is much easier...

**Issue :** What I am trying to do it to automatically fill in some cells depending on the user input in a previous cell.

**Situation :** I have an access database table called *Overview* which will be filled row by row by a user. I set the primary key as ShipmentID so that whenever he starts a new row, he has to first enter this value.

[image]

Afterwards, when the user enters the DealerNo, I want the 3 next information(DealerName, Country,ShipperContact) to be filled in respectively.

The information comes from an other table *DealerLookup* which lists all the different dealers and gather all their information.

The *DealerLookup* contains those 3 information in the columns CompanyName, Country, ContactName respectively while the primary key from this table is the DealerNo.

**Attempt :** This doesn't work at all though, so I hope you can help me out with the structure.

```
INSERT INTO Overview (DealerName, Country, ShipperContact)
WHERE DealerNo = 50535
SELECT CompanyName , Country , ContactName FROM DealerLookupNew 
WHERE DealerNo =  Overview.DealerNo ;
```

**Remark :**

1. Even if it would work, it wouldn't be a good solution since this is valid for only one DealerNo. So it would work only for that row, but if the user enters an other DealerNo this code wouldn't make anything...A good solution ( which I don't know how to write in SQL) would be to replace 50535 with the value of the last non-empty cell in DealerNo.
2. If I delete `WHERE DealerNo = 50535` then the error comes from the last line because `Overview.DealerNo` isn't the right way to say "take the value of the last non-empty cell in DealerNo form the *Overview* table"

Any ideas how to do this ?

Comment: I would write and run an excel macro to fill in the empty cells before exporting to access.

Comment: Yeah but the thing is that this Access will be updated ( new rows entered or deleted) everyday. The data is currently on excel but since it's a really heavy document it makes each operation really slow  that's why I want to transfer the whole thing on Access and avoid exporting several times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to do this in a Datasheet view.  What you need is the AfterUpdate event, which is not available on a Datasheet view.

I'm pretty sure the only way to do this would be to add fields to a form and do the calculation in the AfterUpdate event of DealerNo.  It's going to change the way your users enter data, but it will give you a lot more flexibility to manipulate data than a standard Datasheet view will.

Or, as Dan suggested in a comment, just do all the work in Excel before you import it.  However, this won't help you moving forward, once all your data is in Access and you're entering new records.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Johnny, I will start looking at Forms then since I tried to avoid them so far and will let you know

Comment: Do you know a way to link the form to the table so that the AfterUpdate event is run when the user enters the DealerNo is the table ?

Comment: If you specify a table as the form's RecordSource, then the table is automatically updated as you enter data.  This is fine for a beginner, but if you leave the form unbound (no RecordSource specified) you have a little more flexibility in terms of how and when a record is saved.  Either way you do it, in the AfterUpdate event of the textbox for DealerNo, just use DLookup to fill in the other textboxes.  So one line would be: Me.txtCompanyName = DLookup("CompanyName", "DealerLookupNew", "DealerNo = '" & Me.txtDealerNo & "'")

Comment: This DLookup function is exactly what I was looking for. If I type `MsgBox DLookup("CompanyName", "DealerLookupNew", "DealerName = 36288")` I get the right CompanyName but otherwise I always get an error for the criterion part, so I'll try to fix this, but thanks for the help !

Comment: You probably already know this but I'll say it anyway; if you're using an Integer then you don't use the single quotes around the variable that I put in my DLookup code above.  If you are using a Text, then you need the single quotes around the variable.

Comment: Yes, I know this...I tried lots of different possibilities ( Integer doesn't actually since  the DealerNo is always over 32000) but it didn't work and only now I managed to get it with this `MsgBox DLookup("CompanyName", "DealerLookupNew", "DealerNo = " & DealerNo.Value)` which returns the right value !